# Validar la Ñ en Java

Tags: java, xml, jsp

Estoy tratando de guardar en un String de Java (para generar un fichero xml más adelante) unos datos de pantalla (cargados en un jsp). El problema es que cuando guardo en dicho String una "ñ" se genera un carácter raro (una cajita con interrogante dentro) y a la hora de generar dicho xml se produce un casque. Me gustaría saber cómo guardar la letra "ñ" para que luego aparezca en el xml.

Este es que utilizo(el primer método llama al segundo, estaba de antes en la aplicación):

```
public static Document creaNuevoDocumento(String entrada){
        try {
            byte[] bs = entrada.getBytes();
            InputStream ip = new ByteArrayInputStream(bs);
            return creaNuevoDocumento(ip);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Document creaNuevoDocumento(InputStream entrada) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setValidating(false);
            //dbf.setAttribute("xml","version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"");

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = db.parse(entrada);
            return document;
        } catch (Throwable exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: Deberías leer por favor [ask], a tu pregunta le faltan detalles relevantes y esto puede causar su cierre

Comment: Cual es el error que sale al generar el xml??? que un caracter se vea como un cuadradito en una ide no dice nada, porque puede ser un problema de codificiacion de la ide y como muestra los caracteres... cual es el codigo que usas para generar el xml?

Comment: He añadido el codigo, no se guardo en su momento al crearlo. Disculpad.

Answer (score 1):

Usa la codificaciòn "utf-8" para guardar el archivo.

Lee datos usando codificaciòn "utf-8":

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
```

escribe archivo .xml usando codificaciòn "utf-8":

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream(filePath, true), "utf-8");
```

De esta forma todas las acentuaciones incluida la "ñ" y "Ñ" se guardaràn sin problema en el archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]